# I want to go all Ubuntu. How can I get my HP laptop with UEFI to boot Ubuntu directly?

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I'm a bit fed up with Windows 10. I am currently dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Now I'm in favor of Ubuntu, so now I want to go all Ubuntu and uninstall Windows 10 entirely.

My main problem is that the the BIOS menu on my HP laptop (HP Pavilion x360 13-inch) won't allow me to prioritize the Ubuntu entry over the Windows entry, so even if I were to uninstall Windows, if I forget to hit the F9 key on my computer, it will go into recovery mode and try to install Windows again.

What I want is to have my laptop run and only boot into Ubuntu. No more of this Windows crap. This is why I've come here, because I need help.

I want to completely clean my hard drive. Is it safe for me to delete every single partition, including the EFI partition and all recovery partitions? Can I create a brand new EFI partition? If there are partitions I cannot delete, which ones am I not to touch? Here's my partition table:

`Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1333247   1331200   650M unknown
/dev/sda2    1333248   1865727    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1865728   2127871    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2127872 660847296 658719425 314.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  660848640 929282047 268433408   128G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  929284096 931067903   1783808   871M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  931069952 932798463   1728512   844M unknown
/dev/sda8  932798464 976762879  43964416    21G Microsoft basic data`

Also, if I create a new EFI partition, what is it like? What useful options will be available for me? Or will it be very bare bones?

I may ask more questions here later, hopefully this and other questions won't be too difficult. If I manage to go all Ubuntu, I'd like to help out on the Ask Ubuntu site and answer some basic questions asked by new users. I'm pretty experienced with Ubuntu, so I might be able to make myself useful here :-)

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit:** I successfully uninstalled Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu. I deleted every partition except the first two (the WINRE and EFI partitions). I used `efibootmgr` to set Ubuntu to boot by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `efibootmgr`.  EFI boot works through a small configuration file that states which boot options are there.  `efibootmgr` allows you to tinker with those, delete unnecessary ones, and change the boot order.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to disable Secure Boot from BIOS Setup. Then, boot from a bootable Ubuntu USB. Use GParted to delete the Windows partition (and any other Windows Recovery partitions). Install and run boot-repair.

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot is *usually* unnecessary. It provides some (admittedly mostly theoretical right now) benefits, so leaving it enabled makes some sense unless you have evidence that it's causing problems.

Comment: According to Microsoft's website https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx it says "Secure Boot helps to make sure that your PC boots using only firmware that is trusted by the manufacturer." which is in this case Windows. So, I'm guessing that there is a high probability that it would cause problems.

Comment: DrAlani, that quote is in reference to the firmware in video cards and the like. Ubuntu has long supported Secure Boot via an EFI pre-GRUB program called Shim. Shim is signed by Microsoft and so will run on computers with Microsoft's (third-party) public key installed. Beyond theory, I can report that I've run Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) on many computers with Secure Boot enabled -- enough that I wouldn't care to offer a count. Only two have exhibited Secure Boot-related problems, and one of those was fixed by a firmware update.

Answer (score 0):

did you happen to check out the documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

I was in your boat and I disabled UEFI, but that was years ago (6) on my laptop and I just never wanted to go back. That was in the early days though with many improvements since then.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you've already done what you wanted, but to directly answer your question, yes, you can safely delete all the partitions and re-install Ubuntu. The installer will create a new ESP (or you should create one yourself, either using the installer's partitioner or before you launch the installer). The ESP is simply a FAT partition with a particular type code (EF00 in `gdisk` or the "boot flag" set in libparted-based tools). I recommend a size of 550MiB, simply because that's an easy-to-remember value that's larger than various problem points a little below that value.

With all Windows partitions gone, the firmware won't have any Windows recovery tools to launch, so there'll be no chance of it doing so. The greatest risk in this approach is that the firmware might still refuse to launch GRUB by default -- some EFIs are just plain broken and won't launch anything but the Windows boot loader, or at least what they *think* is the Windows boot loader, based on its filename or the description in the NVRAM. This problem is rarer today than it was a few years ago, but it still sometimes crops up.